# Set UITextField to a "selected state" upon dismissing an alert

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitextfield, uialertview

I'm practicing on iOS development and I'm currently making a BMI Calculator app.

Apart from the labels, the view includes 2 UITextFields - `height_TextField` and `weight_TextField`, and a UIButton `calculateBMI`.

I have implemented if/else conditions to catch all empty text fields. Meaning if a user leaves `height_TextField` or `weight_TextField` or **BOTH** blank, a *UIAlertView* pops up telling the user to fill in the required fields.

---

### **Help:**

I want the respective UITextField to be "selected" or be in the "editable" state (Cursor and keyboard appears and ready for input) upon dismissing the alert. I have tried adding the  protocol to my .h file and implementing the

`- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`

and I think the idea might be implementing a code relevant to "`[self.height_TextField editingMode??]`" in the method but I can't figure this out.

---

This is the source code for my `BMICalculatorViewController.m` file:

http://pastebin.com/LiwbscNg

I have not touched the `.h` file (No variables or methods declared there.)

Thank you in advance for your kind help/solutions. If you have more time to spare, any tips and best practices would be appreciated as well! Thanks!

Comment: All you need to do is call `[self.height_TextField becomeFirstResponder];`

Answer (score 0):

`becomeFirstResponder` is the method you need to call on the textfield , bring it in editing mode.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
      [self.height_TextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
```